# insert data not working php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

good day guys,

can you help to solve this problem this is a sample script for my assignment. I am having a problem regarding on insertion of data in mysql.

```
<?php 


 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {    

        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $contact = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contact']);
        $room = $_POST['room'];
        $adult = $_POST['adult'];
        $children = $_POST['children'];
        $arrival = $_POST['arrival'];
        $departure = $_POST['departure'];
        $date = date("Y/m/d H:i:s");
        $status = "Confirmed";

        $query = "INSERT INTO booking VALUES('".$name."','".$email."','".$contact."','".$room."','".$adult."','".$children."','".$arrival."','".$departure."','".$date."','".$status."')";
        if(mysql_query($query)){
            ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"  style="text-align:center; margin-top: 200px; background-color: #fff;" >
                    <p>New reservation has successfully sent!</p>
                </div> 
            <?php 
            header("refresh:2;url=/index.php");
        }
        else{
            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. ";
        }
    }
?>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="reserve.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="focusedinput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control1" id="focusedinput" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" autofocus="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="focusedinput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control1" id="focusedinput" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="focusedinput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Contact</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control1" id="focusedinput" name="contact" placeholder="Enter Contact Number">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="selector1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Select Room</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select name="room" id="selector1" class="form-control1">
            <option value="null">Select Type of Room</option>
            <optgroup label="Dorm Type">
                <option value="aguila">Aguila Room</option>
                <option value="rizal">Rizal Room</option>
                <option value="kalabaw">Kalabaw Room</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Private Room">
                <option value="sampaguita">Sampaguita Room</option>
                <option value="bahay_kubo">Bahay Kubo Room</option>
                <option value="tinikling">Tinikling Room</option>
                <option value="kalesa">Kalesa Room</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="focusedinput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Adult</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <select name="adult" id="selector1" class="form-control1">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>         
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <label for="focusedinput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Children</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <select name="children" id="selector1" class="form-control1">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>         
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="focusedinput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Arrival Date</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control1 date" id="datepicker1" type="text" name="arrival" value="DD/MM/YY" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'DD/MM/YY';}">

        </div>
        <label for="focusedinput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Departure Date</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control1 date" id="datepicker1" type="text" name="departure" value="DD/MM/YY" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'DD/MM/YY';}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"> </div><br><br>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <div class="row"><br>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-success btn" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

when I clicked the submit button there's nothings happen. TY

Comment: Please show your HTML code too

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated try to use MYSQLi_* or PDO

Comment: The usual comment for stuff like this: your code is wide open to SQL injection attacks. It is recommended that you stop using the old and long since deprecated `mysql` extension and switch to the modern `mysqli` extension or `PDO`. Then learn about the advantages of "prepared statements" and "parameter binding". Please see the documentation about this issue.

Comment: in your html do you have a `form` action pointing to the right file? and your input type, is it `submit`?

Comment: @ObjectManipulator i already update my post

Comment: Please be more precise. What _exactly_ does "I am having a problem " mean? What happens? _Exactly_? And what do you see in your http servers error log file?

Comment: @arkascha this just a sample. but still i want to learn the mysql.

Comment: Nothing against learning, certainly not. But you should not learn the usage of clearly deprecated tools. Especially since you appear to know about that issue... Use the right tools from the start, otherwise you will _not_ learn important parts.

Comment: where is mysql connection ??????????? i think missing mysql connection string

Comment: echo your query and execute in phpmyadmin will let you know the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note:** Usage of mysql extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

You have made some few mistakes so that the query might not be inserting datas into the phpmyadmin database. The basic error you have made is in the insert query by not concatenating the values that you want in the VALUES section and the insert statement syntax will be like this.

Insert Syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

> Note: If a column is AUTO_INCREMENT (like the "id" column) or TIMESTAMP (like the "reg_date" column), it is no need to be specified in the SQL query; MySQL will automatically add the value.

Replace your Insert Code with the following

```
$query = "INSERT INTO booking(`name`,`email`,`contact`,`room`,`adult`,`children`,`arrival`,`departure`,`date`,`status`) VALUES('".$name."','".$email."','".$contact."','".$room."','".$adult."','".$children."','".$arrival."','".$departure."','".$date."','".$status."')";
```

Ensure all the values that i give in the table(`column1`,`column2`) are correct as per the table structure that you have.

**Mysql Connectivity**

You are missing mysql connectivity code in the code that you have provided.
Ensure that you have placed the connectivity code to your file.

```
<?php
   $dbhost = 'localhost';
   $dbuser = 'root';
   $dbpass = '';
   $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
   if(! $conn )
   {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   echo 'Connected successfully';
   mysql_select_db( 'TUTORIALS' );
   mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

> **Note:** You first put echo to the Insert Statement and then break the execution by putting the exit; and you copy the statement that is echoed and place it in SQL of the DB and then check whether any error occurs in insertion. If no error occurs remove the echo and delete the exit;

And after all the check i am suggesting you to check the Note that i have mentioned just above to this line since it will be delivering you with the perfect error what you have made.

Comment: if he does have an `ID` field, your answer might be correct

Comment: Ya that is correct but the basic Insert Query requires the `table column` names right for insert. He is missing that

Comment: true, but if the values he provided exactly matches the number of columns he has in the database, it might still work

Comment: Yup @TheFlash. That is the thing i have asked him to do in the `Last Note` that i have made in my answer to put echo and break the execution there itself bu placing exit after that line.

Comment: @NareshKumar.P i' already tried it but still not working . I already have a mysql connection

Comment: Follow the last note first. And then let me know where you face error

Comment: This One=>Note: You first put echo to the Insert Statement and then break the execution by putting the exit; and you copy the statement that is echoed and place it in SQL of the DB and then check whether any error occurs in insertion. If no error occurs remove the echo and delete the exit;

Comment: I already tried it but the only says is ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql.

Comment: Are you seeing the query in the page after you put echo

Comment: Copy the query and paste into the SQL section in phpmyadmin under your DB created.

Comment: After you click on GO in the SQL of phpmyadmin you can see how the query executes

Comment: @NareshKumar.P #1062 - Duplicata du champ '' pour la clef 'user_name'

Comment: You have this Error: Duplicate field '' for key 'user_name.

Comment: Please fix that. And after that you run the query again

Comment: You have provide unique for user name ah in Database

Comment: If my answer is found useful you can accept it so that it will be useful for others who face the same error next time.

Comment: Accepting answer : Follow this link -> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: It is a mutual help that you give every developer who helps you to rectify your error by awarding the credits for his/her answer they has provided you. But you are missing that bro:)

Answer (score 1):

It is not looking any error in code , Please check your database table structure about each fields , If you are not sure then please add column name also in like INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2) VALUES (value1, value2 ),
You might have some more/additional columns in you database Table , Please double check that .

Comment: Can you please share you Db table structure , I will  provide you error free code . Also Which php version are you using .

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check whether condition is true mean check the control going inside your condition `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ //code}` put `die('inside condition')` for the check.

Then you should insert with `INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)`

after mysql_query you should write the `echo mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error() . "\n";` for the get the error and find out what is the error occur during the execution.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_* is Deprecated try to use mysqli_* or PDO

> Warning mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array,mysql_connect etc.. extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.
>   Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

```
            //db connection

         global $conn;

            $servername = "localhost";  //host name

            $username = "username"; //username

            $password = "password"; //password

            $mysql_database = "dbname"; //database name

        //mysqli prepared statement 

            $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

           mysqli_select_db($conn,$mysql_database) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");





                if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {    

                        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
                        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
                        $contact = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contact']);
                        $room = $_POST['room'];
                        $adult = $_POST['adult'];
                        $children = $_POST['children'];
                        $arrival = $_POST['arrival'];
                        $departure = $_POST['departure'];
                        $date = date("Y/m/d H:i:s");
                        $status = "Confirmed";

                     $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO booking (`name`,`email`,`contact`,`room`,`adult`,`children`,`arrival`,`departure`,`date`,`status`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

                    $stmt->bind_param('ssssssssss',$name,$email,$contact,$room,$adult,$children,$arrival,$departure,$date,$status);

                    //The argument may be one of four types:

                    //i - integer
                    //d - double
                    //s - string
                    //b - BLOB
                    //change it by respectively 

                    $stmt->execute();

                    $row_count= $stmt->affected_rows;
                    $stmt->close();
                     $conn->close();



                        if($row_count>0){
                            ?>
                                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"  style="text-align:center; margin-top: 200px; background-color: #fff;" >
                                    <p>New reservation has successfully sent!</p>
                                </div> 
                            <?php 
                            header("refresh:2;url=/index.php");
                        }
                        else{
                            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. ";
                        }
                }
            ?>
```